# Use second cursor in cursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a database like

```
--------------------------------------------------
| _id| poi_id  | poi_name    |poi_address        |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 101     | sight_1     |sight_1_adr        |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 101     | sight_2     |sight_2_adr        |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 100     | sight_3     |sight_3_adr        |
-------------------------------------------------- 
| 4  | 101     | sight_4     |sight_4_adr        |
--------------------------------------------------
| 5  | 100     | sight_5     |sight_5_adr        |
--------------------------------------------------
```

First of all , i want to create a listview and group my data by "poi_id".

I use the following query:

```
"SELECT* FROM poi_table GROUP BY poi_id"
```

I use a cursor with that query and i create the list view as:

```
            entry.open();
            Cursor cursor = entry.getData();
            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), cursor);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

My problem is that, in every list row, i would like to print also the poi_name of every poi_id.So iwould like to have something like:

```
-------------------------------
            -101-
           sight 1
           sight 2
           sight 4
-------------------------------
            -100-
           sight 3
           sight 5
-------------------------------
             etc
```

This is where i stack!
In my CustomCursorAdapter, i get the poi_id as:

```
String ID = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(db.POI_ID));
```

and then i use a second cursor to get the data like:

```
Cursor c2 = entry.getDatabyID(ID);
            for (int i = 0; i < entry.fetchPlacesCountByID(ID); i++) {
                                c2.moveToPosition(i);
                                String name= c2
                                        .getString(c2
                                                .getColumnIndex(db.POINT_NAME));}
```

and i create dynamically a new textView and i set the string name there as text.

How can i fix it?That way doesnt crash but i get as many poi_names as i scroll down..